# Processing a Django form when there are multiple possibilities?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

What is the correct way to process a Django form within a view if you don't know which form to expect when entering the view?  I have a view which determines the type of form to render based on a session variable:

```
# views.py
def enter_location(request):
    country = request.session['country']
    if request.method == "POST":
        if country == 'US':
            form = USLocationForm(request.POST)
        elif country == 'GB':
            form = GBLocationForm(request.POST)
        elif country == 'CA':
            form = CALocationForm(request.POST)
        else:
            form = OtherLocationForm(request.POST)    
        if form.is_valid():
            # do stuff...
            pass
    else:
        if country == 'US':
            form = USLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        elif country == 'GB':
            form = GBLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        elif country == 'CA':
            form = CALocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        else:
            form = OtherLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Clearly this is ugly code and it doesn't scale as I add more countries.  I tried to keep my view short by determining the form type via a helper function:

```
# views.py
from location.forms import LocationForm
def enter_location(request):
    country = request.session['country']
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LocationForm.get_form(country)
        submitted_form = form(request.POST)
        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            # do stuff...
            pass
    else:
        form = LocationForm.get_form(country)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)

# location/forms.py
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices = choices.COUNTRIES_AND_EMPTY,)
    city = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_form(country):
        if country == 'US':
            return form = USLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        elif country == 'GB':
            return form = GBLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        elif country == 'CA':
            return form = CALocationForm(initial={'country': country})
        else:
            return form = OtherLocationForm(initial={'country': country})
```

The problem is that when the view runs, I get "TypeError "'USLocationForm' object is not callable"" at the line:

```
submitted_form = form(request.POST)
```

This also happens when country is 'GB' or 'CA' and the appropriate form has been chosen.  I ran the debugger and did "type(form)" using both views and the form attributes appear to be the same in either case.  Is there something different happening when you first instantiate the form in the GET block versus instantiating it again during the POST and then populating it with the posted data? What's the Django way of handling this situation when one of many possible forms can be chosen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "right way" to handle this, but one thing you could do to consolidate is use a mapping.

Example:

```
form_mappings = {
    'US': USLocationForm,
    'GB': GBLocationForm,
    #...
}

def enter_location(request):
    country = request.session['country']
    country_form = form_mappings.get(country, OtherLocationForm)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = country_form(request.POST)
        #...
    else:
        form = country_form(initial={'country': country})
```

This way, you can extend the code for further countries, and not have to change the code at all..

Comment: Thanks for sharing this technique!  It works equally well for selecting the appropriate template which also depends on the country.